# Loading alternative class implementations in zend (1.11)

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

Is it possible to override the existing class definitions using the autoloader, making the loader find my code first and load it instead of the zend library code?  So that I can write my own `Zend_View_Helper_FormText` and have all text `Form_Elements` automatically get my version instead of the default one?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

So i wanted to make sure i was correct since its been a bit since ive used ZF. The following worked for me out of the box.

Create a custom `YourNamespace_Application_Resource_View` in `LIBRARY_PATH/YourNamespace/Application/Resource/View` with a 'setHelperPaths` method - or whatever you want to call it in configuration.

```
class YourNamespace_Application_Resource_View extends Zend_Application_Resource_View
{
   public function setHelperPaths($paths){
     if(!empty($paths)){
       $view = $this->getView();
       foreach($paths as $ns => $path) {
          $view->addHelperPath($path, $ns);
       }
     }
   }
}
```

Then in your config do someting like:

```
all:
  pluginPaths:
    'YourNamespace_Application_Resource_': <?php echo LIBRARY_PATH ?>/YourNamespace/Application/Resource

  resources:
    view:
      helperPaths:
        'YourNamespace_View_Helper': <?php echo LIBRARY_PATH ?>/YourNamespace/View/Helper
```

Obviously this doesnt completely replace anything you already have configured... its in addition to. Also i have my project generator in Zend_Tool set up to use YAML (with sfYaml) as my config format so if you use INI or XML you will need to convert appropriately.

Then you just create your cutsom helper with the same name as the zend one you are overriding. I used the following example in my test:

```
// File in LIBRARY_PATH/YourNamespace/View/Helper/FormText.php
class YourNamespace_View_Helper_FormText extends Zend_View_Helper_FormText
{
   public function formText($name, $value = null, $attribs = null)
   {
      $xhtml = parent::formText($name, $value, $attribs);
      $xhtml .= '<br /> <pre>'.__CLASS__.'</pre>';
      return $xhtml;
   }
}
```

And then it automagically worked. If it doesnt work for you then there is probably something else in the mix thats giving it issues.

---

Why dont you just create your own implementation in your own "namespace" (eg. `Someguy_View_Helper_FormText`) and then load that? [If you put it on top of the helper path stack the plugin loader will use that instead of the Zend version automatically](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.paths).

Comment: I was under the impression that if it is in a different namespace, then zend won't try to load it, as it is trying to load Zend_View_Helper_FormText specifically, not just any Namespace_View_Helper_FormText.  Doing $view->setHelperPath() in my Bootstrap.php doesn't seem to work, either for a Someguy_ namespace or using the Zend_ namespace.

Comment: Then you may need to override the `Zend_Form_Decorator_ViewHelper` so that it pulls your helpers instead.

Comment: Basically what im getting at here is that it is bad form to replace `Zend_*` with your own implementation, you should instead be creating whatever it is in your own namespace and then loading it appropriately. Depending on what youre replacing, overloading the defaults may be a tedious or a quick and simple task, but doing it the wrong way is just bad form (no pun intended haha).

Comment: I'd rather have it be in my own namespace, but there doesn't appear to be any way to have it loaded automatically that way?  I just want to replace the default View_Helper_FormText with one that doesn't mangle the output, without having to go through and do it manually in every single element of every single form in the entire application.

Comment: It doesn't matter.  The output generated by Zend_View_Helper_FormText is not suitable.  I wrote a replacement _View_Helper_FormText to generate the output I need.  I just can't figure out how to override the default Zend_View_Helper_FormText with my version.

Comment: Actually it does matter, because if its a case of the wrapping HTML elements those can be adjsuted by changing the decorators used for a form element. This can be done progamtically during instation of you form class, or by extending Zend_Form with a replacement bae class that sets default decorators, or it can be done by parsing configuration when you create your form instance.

Comment: Given that the class in question is like 10 lines long, and that I obviously had to read the code to write a replacement for it, it should be fairly obvious that what I need to change can not be changed via existing methods.  It is hard-coded into the formText method.  The question is "is there a way to have zend load a replacement class instead of the default", and it applies to any case where the zend implementation hard codes things that someone needs to change, not just this particular example.

Comment: I jsut tried it and it worked out of the box... Ill post what i did but perhaps you shoudl post how youre configuring it.